# PHP-MSSQL - Running complex SQL script in PHP with MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to run a rather complex SQL script that works great in SQL Manager.
After a few hurdles to get my php server to connect to MSSQL, simple scripts (selects) work however this script I'm trying to re-use returns nothing.

Script is as below:

```sql
--=====================================================================================================================
-- Step 1.9.10: Cleanup existing temporary tables.
--=====================================================================================================================
if exists ( select * from tempdb..sysobjects    where   id = object_id('tempdb..#CU_RPT_PJ', 'U'))
begin
    Drop Table #CU_RPT_PJ
end


--=====================================================================================================================
select
    -- The resulting non-pivoted columns.
        Em_M_Id             = pvt.Em_M_Id                       
    ,   EmCd                        = pvt.EmCd                      
    ,   DisplayName                 = pvt.DisplayName               
    ,   PCal_ClsDate                = pvt.PCal_ClsDate
    ,   PayCalcBatch_Id             = pvt.PayCalcBatch_Id
    ,   PCalendar_Id                = pvt.PCalendar_Id
    -- The Link Table data from : [ HM_EmpDept_Link ].
    ,   OrgNode_Code                    = cast(Null AS nvarchar(50))
    ,   OrgNode_SName                   = cast(Null AS nvarchar(50))
    ,   OrgNode_LName                   = cast(Null AS nvarchar(80))
    ,   OrgNode_CostCode                = cast(Null AS nvarchar(50))
    ,   TreePath_SDesc                  = cast(Null AS nvarchar(255))
    ,   TreePath_LDesc                  = cast(Null AS nvarchar(255))

-- The resulting pivoted columns.
,[catc - Unit]                  = pvt.[01]
,[catc - Amt]                   = pvt.[02]
,[MlAllo - Amt]                 = pvt.[03]
,[BaSalCat - Unit]  = pvt.[04]
,[BaSalCat - Amt]   = pvt.[05]
,[Otr 1.5 - Unit]           = pvt.[06]
,[Otr 1.5 - Amt]            = pvt.[07]
,[Otr 2.0 - Unit]           = pvt.[08]
,[Otr 2.0 - Amt]            = pvt.[09]
,[Otr 3.0 - Unit]           = pvt.[10]
,[Otr 3.0 - Amt]            = pvt.[11]
,[Ilv - Unit]                   = pvt.[12]
,[Ilv - Amt]                    = pvt.[13]
,[Slv - Unit]                   = pvt.[14]
,[Slv - Amt]                        = pvt.[15]
,[Llv - Unit]                   = pvt.[16]
,[Llv - Amt]                    = pvt.[17]
,[Plv - Unit]               = pvt.[18]
,[Plv - Amt]                = pvt.[19]
,[Mlv - Unit]               = pvt.[20]
,[Mlv - Amt]                = pvt.[21]
,[Wdg - Unit]                       = pvt.[22]
,[Wlv - Amt]                    = pvt.[23]
,[BFn - Amt]                = pvt.[24]
,[AtB - Amt]                = pvt.[25]
,[RdfP - Amt]               = pvt.[26]
,[RdHP - Amt]               = pvt.[27]
,[Adj - Amt]                        = pvt.[28]
,[TEarn - Amt]                  = pvt.[29]
,[Nem - Amt]                    = pvt.[30]
,[NsE - Amt]                    = pvt.[31]
,[TEmo Curr - Amt]          = pvt.[32]
,[BfA - Amt]                = pvt.[33]
,[AbF - Amt]            = pvt.[34]
,[Lded - Amt]                   = pvt.[35]
,[MfpCon - Amt]             = pvt.[36]
,[Npy - Amt]                        = pvt.[37]                  
,[UdAm - Amt]           = pvt.[38]  
,[CunCon - Amt]     = pvt.[39]  
,[IncTxPc   - Amt]      = pvt.[40]  
,[ULv]                  = pvt.[41]  
,[UpSck]                            = pvt.[42]  
,[IunpLv]                   = pvt.[43]  
,[SPdLv - Unit]         = pvt.[44]  
,[SPdLv - Amt]              = pvt.[45]  
,[SUPdLv]                   = pvt.[46]  
,[VcUnpLv]              = pvt.[47]  
,[BnLH - Amt]               = pvt.[48]
,[VcPdLv - Unit]            = pvt.[49]  
,[VcPdLv - Amt]         = pvt.[50]  
,[SvAl]                 = pvt.[51]  
,[SsPdLv]               = pvt.[52]  
,[EyBnC]                        = pvt.[53]  
,[RLlv]                 = pvt.[54]  
,[RSLv]                 = pvt.[55]  


into    #CU_RPT_PJ
from    (
        select  
            -- These columns used for as non-pivoted columns.
                pct.Em_M_Id
            ,   pct.EmCd
            ,   pct.DisplayName
            ,   pct.PCal_ClsDate
            ,   pct.PayCalcBatch_Id
            ,   pct.PCalendar_Id
        --  ,   pct.PayCalcStep_Code
        --  ,   pct.PayCalcStep_Seqn
        --  ,   pct.PayCalcTrn_Unit
        --  ,   pct.PayCalcTrn_Amount
        --  ,   Alias_TagName           = sta.Alias_TagName
        --  ,   ValType                 = sta.ValType
        --  ,   sta_PayCalcStep_Code    = sta.PayCalcStep_Code

            -- These columns used for pivoting rows into columns.
            ,   QrySeqn                 = sta.QrySeqn
            ,   Common_Value            = case  sta.ValType     
                                                when    'U' then    pct.PayCalcTrn_Unit
                                                when    'A' then    pct.PayCalcTrn_Amount
                                                else                0.00
                                            end
        from    dbo.vHP_Data_PayCalcTrn_EmpList as pct

        join    (
                    select  Alias_TagName   = 'catc - Unit'                 , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '01'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'catc'                    
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'catc - Amt'                      , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '02'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'catc'                    
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'MlAllo - Amt'                    , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '03'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'MlAllo'  
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'BaSalCat - Unit'     , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '04'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'BaSalCat'    
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'BaSalCat - Amt'      , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '05'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'BaSalCat'    
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Otr 1.5 - Unit'              , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '06'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Otr 1.5' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Otr 1.5 - Amt'               , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '07'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Otr 1.5' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Otr 2.0 - Unit'              , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '08'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Otr 2.0' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Otr 2.0 - Amt'               , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '09'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Otr 2.0' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Otr 3.0 - Unit'              , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '10'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Otr 3.0' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Otr 3.0 - Amt'               , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '11'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Otr 3.0' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Ilv - Unit'                      , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '12'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Ilv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Ilv - Amt'                       , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '13'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Ilv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Slv - Unit'                      , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '14'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Slv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Slv - Amt'                       , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '15'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Slv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Llv - Unit'                      , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '16'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Llv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Llv - Amt'                       , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '17'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Llv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Plv - Unit'                  , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '18'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Plv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Plv - Amt'                   , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '19'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Plv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Mlv - Unit'                  , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '20'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Mlv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Mlv - Amt'                   , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '21'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Mlv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Wdg - Unit'                          , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '22'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Wlv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Wlv - Amt'                       , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '23'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Wlv'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'BFn - Amt'                   , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '24'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'BFn' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'AtB - Amt'                   , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '25'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'AtB' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'RdfP - Amt'              , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '26'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'RdfP'                        
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'RdHP - Amt'              , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '27'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'RdHP'                        
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Adj - Amt'                       , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '28'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Allowance'                       
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'TEarn - Amt'                 , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '29'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'TEarn'   
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Nem - Amt'                       , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '30'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Nem' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'NsE - Amt'                       , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '31'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'NsE' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'TEmo Curr - Amt'             , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '32'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'TEmo Curr'   
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'BfA - Amt'                   , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '33'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'BfA' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'AbF - Amt'               , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '34'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'AbF'                     
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Lded - Amt'                  , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '35'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Lded'    
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'MfpCon - Amt'                , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '36'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'MfpCon'  
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'Npy - Amt'                           , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '37'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'Npy' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'UdAm - Amt'          , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '38'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'UdAm'    
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'CunCon - Amt'            , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '39'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'CunCon'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'IncTxPc - Amt'           , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '40'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'IncTxPc'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'ULv'                     , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '41'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'ULv'         
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'UpSck'                               , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '42'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'UpSck'           
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'IunpLv'                      , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '43'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'IunpLv'          
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'SPdLv - Unit'                , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '44'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'SPdLv'   
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'SPdLv'                       , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '45'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'SPdLv'   
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'SUPdLv'                  , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '46'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'SUPdLv'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'VcUnpLv'                 , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '47'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'VcUnpLv'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'BnLH - Amt'                  , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '48'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'BnLH Amount' 
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'VcPdLv'                      , ValType   = 'U'   , QrySeqn   = '49'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'VcPdLv'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'VcPdLv'                      , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '50'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'VcPdLv'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'SvAl'                        , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '51'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'SvAl'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'SsPdLv'                  , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '52'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'SsPdLv'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'EyBnC'                           , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '53'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'EyBnC'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'RLlv'                        , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '54'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'RLlv'
            union   select  Alias_TagName   = 'RSLv'                        , ValType   = 'A'   , QrySeqn   = '55'  , PayCalcStep_Code  = 'RSLv'

            )   as sta
            on  pct.PayCalcStep_Code    = sta.PayCalcStep_Code

        where   pct.Em_M_Id > 0

            and pct.PayCalcBatch_Id             in ( 

select  pcb.PayCalcBatch_Id 
from    dbo.fHP_Log_PayCalcBatch (0, 1, '', 1, '', 1, '')   as pcb
where   pcb.PayCalcBatch_Id > 0
    and pcb.PayCalGroup_LName = 'Something-1'
    and pcb.PayCalcBatch_Status = 30
    and pcb.PayCalc_SttDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-10'


        )

        )   as pct
    pivot   (
        sum(pct.Common_Value)
    for pct.QrySeqn in (
            [01]
        ,   [02]
        ,   [03]
        ,   [04]
        ,   [05]
        ,   [06]
        ,   [07]
        ,   [08]
        ,   [09]
        ,   [10]
        ,   [11]
        ,   [12]
        ,   [13]
        ,   [14]
        ,   [15]
        ,   [16]
        ,   [17]
        ,   [18]
        ,   [19]
        ,   [20]
        ,   [21]
        ,   [22]
        ,   [23]
        ,   [24]
        ,   [25]
        ,   [26]
        ,   [27]
        ,   [28]
        ,   [29]
        ,   [30]
        ,   [31]
        ,   [32]
        ,   [33]
        ,   [34]
        ,   [35]
        ,   [36]
        ,   [37]
        ,   [38]
        ,   [39]
        ,   [40]
        ,   [41]
        ,   [42]
        ,   [43]
        ,   [44]
        ,   [45]
        ,   [46]
        ,   [47]
        ,   [48]
        ,   [49]
        ,   [50]
        ,   [51]
        ,   [52]
        ,   [53]
        ,   [54]
        ,   [55]
        )    
    )   as pvt

--=====================================================================================================================
-- Step 3.5.21: Update the Dataset with Employee-OrgChart Link Data.
--=====================================================================================================================


update  rpt
    set
        OrgNode_Code                    = edl.OrgNode_Code  
    ,   OrgNode_SName                   = edl.OrgNode_SName 
    ,   OrgNode_LName                   = edl.OrgNode_LName 
    ,   OrgNode_CostCode                = edl.OrgNode_CostCode
    ,   TreePath_SDesc                  = edl.TreePath_SDesc    
    ,   TreePath_LDesc                  = edl.TreePath_LDesc    

from    #CU_RPT_PJ          as rpt

inner join  dbo.vHM_EmpDept_Link            as edl
    on  rpt.Em_M_Id     = edl.Em_M_Id
    and rpt.PCal_ClsDate        between edl.Edl_Date_Joined and edl.Edl_Date_Left_Siml



--=====================================================================================================================
-- Step 4.20 : Return the Datasets.
--=====================================================================================================================
select  rpt.EmCd, rpt.DisplayName, rpt.PCal_ClsDate, rpt.PayCalcBatch_Id, rpt.[MlAllo - Amt], rpt.[BaSalCat - Amt], rpt.[Otr 1.5 - Amt], rpt.[Otr 2.0 - Amt], rpt.[Otr 3.0 - Amt], rpt.[Ilv - Amt], rpt.[Slv - Amt], rpt.[Llv - Amt], rpt.[Plv - Amt], rpt.[Mlv - Amt], rpt.[Wlv - Amt], rpt.[BFn - Amt], rpt.[AtB - Amt], rpt.[RdfP - Amt], rpt.[RdHP - Amt],rpt.[Adj - Amt], rpt.[TEarn - Amt], rpt.[Nem - Amt], rpt.[NsE - Amt], rpt.[TEmo Curr - Amt], rpt.[BfA - Amt], rpt.[AbF - Amt], rpt.[Lded - Amt], rpt.[MfpCon - Amt],rpt.[Npy - Amt], rpt.[UdAm - Amt], rpt.[CunCon - Amt], rpt.[IncTxPc   - Amt], rpt.[ULv], rpt.[UpSck], rpt.[IunpLv], rpt.[SPdLv - Amt], rpt.[SUPdLv], rpt.[VcPdLv - Amt], rpt.[BnLH - Amt], rpt.[VcPdLv - Amt], rpt.[SvAl], rpt.[SsPdLv], rpt.[EyBnC], rpt.[RLlv], rpt.[RSLv]
from    #CU_RPT_PJ  as rpt
where   rpt.EmCd = '12345'
order by PCal_ClsDate
```

Part of PHP Code used (credentials omitted) $query= Same as SQL above.
Method for retrieving is probably wrong. I've been trying a few, although I'm open to suggestions :)

```
<?php

$connectionInfo = array("UID"=>$myUser, "PWD"=>$myPass, "Database"=>$myDB);

$dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($myServer,$connectionInfo)
or die ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));



$query = "Same query as above verbatim"

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $query) or die ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));


echo "Result \n";
//display the results
print_r($result);


while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) or die ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)))
{

  echo "<li>" . $row[0] ."-". $row[1] ."-". $row[2] . "</li>";


}


sqlsrv_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

print_r($result); //Returns the following:

```
Result Resource id #3Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -28 [code] => -28 [2] => The active result for the query contains no fields. [message] => The active result for the query contains no fields. ) )
```

Comment: Can You show us how are You executing this query and handling it's result? Because it looks like not just one query, but more queries in one SQL script (drop table, select, update, select) - from PHP You can call just one query at a time... So You would have to split the script into partial queries and call them one after each from PHP...

Comment: The question is **why** do you need it to run from php? Why don't your wrap it into a stored procedure and call this procedure from php?

Comment: @shadyyx I'll append my post with the PHP script used. It's quite a mess sorry about that. You're right there's quite a few queries going on. Would you have a suggestion as to how to split it up? I'm quite a novice to anything beyond simple php+db manipulation.

Comment: @peterm That looks simpler indeed however I don't have any right to add a stored procedure at this point. Hence why I'm looking at alternatives

Comment: Hmm, I thought splitting the query up is the way, but it is not since the first huge select selects data into an object that is further handled in following queries. Since mssql nor sqlsrv has no possibility to run multiple queries in one call You would have to create a stored procedure for this - when You do not have the permissions - ask for them. If they do not want to give You the permission, then ask them to create this stored procedure and give them Your SQL for this... I do not see any other option here...

Comment: @shadyyx Alright thanks for looking into it. I was just looking for a definitive answer to know if there was something I was missing.

Comment: Nope, You are not missing anything, the only problem is that PHP drivers (and libraries) for any database handling are not capable of handling multiple queries returning some response except the PHP's `mysqli::multi_query()` for MySQL DB. But I never heard of any other driver capable of this... **Maybe You could also try to to encapsulate all Your queries into SQL-T procedure body and then call this procedure body from PHP** as it will be just one script that should return only the final result...

Comment: Right now I don't know how to do that encapsulation. I'll look into it. If you got pointers that'd be great.